# Value of definite integral involving $\tan^3(x)$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the value of $$ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+\tan^3x} $$

My attempt: I split $\tan x$ as $\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$, and got the following form
$$ \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos^3x\,\mathrm dx}{\sin^3x+\cos^3x} $$ and am stuck there.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to use partial fractions to solve an integral?

Comment: I wonder if $tan \text x$ is continuous on $\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @Crazy It's in the denominator, so the entire fraction tends to $0$, no problem there.

Comment: just a side note: the improper integral can be simplified to $$2\int_{y\pi}^{(y+1)\pi}\frac{\mathrm dx}{1+\tan^3 x}$$ for any $y\in\Bbb R$ because $\tan x$ is $\pi$-periodic and also it is the integrand.

Comment: A nice one here!

Comment: This integral is divergent because at $3\pi/4$ and $7\pi/4$ it goes to $\infty$ and the integral function $F(x)=\frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{6} \log (\tan (x)+1)+\frac{1}{4} \log \left(\tan ^2(x)+1\right)-\frac{1}{3}\log\left(\tan ^2(x)-\tan (x)+1\right)$ diverges

Comment: @Raffaele: $\log(x)$ diverges at $x\to 0^+$, but $\int_{0}^{1}\log(x)\,dx$ is finite. The issue here is that the integration path goes through simple poles (non-integrable singularities), but the principal value of the integral does exist, and it equals $\color{red}{\pi}$.

Answer (score 4):

**PARTIAL SOLUTION:**
$$\int \frac{dx}{1+\tan^3 x}$$
$$=\int \frac{dx}{(1+\tan x)(1-\tan x+\tan^2 x)}$$
Then use the substitution $x \to \arctan u$:
$$=\int \frac{du}{(1+u)(1-u+u^2)(1+u^2)}$$
Then proceed to use partial fractions. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Substitutions should be given by differentiable maps with a differentiable inverse, but $\tan(x)$ is not injective over $(0,2\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: the partial decomposition of your integral is given by $$1/3\,{\frac {-2\,u+1}{{u}^{2}-u+1}}+1/6\, \left( 1+u \right) ^{-1}+1/2
\,{\frac {1+u}{{u}^{2}+1}}
$$
but the definite integral doesn't converge on the given interval

Comment: The partial fraction decomposition (of what?) is irrelevant for proving the integral is divergent.

Answer (score 1):

The integrand function has simple poles (non-integrable singularities) at $x\in\left\{\frac{3\pi}{4},\frac{7\pi}{4}\right\}\subset\left(0,2\pi\right)$ hence the integral is not convergent in the usual sense.
 Its [principal value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value), however, is finite:

$$\begin{eqnarray*}\text{PV}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{1+\tan^3(x)} &=& \int_{0}^{3\pi/4}\left(\frac{1}{1+\tan^3\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}+x\right)}+\frac{1}{1+\tan^3\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}-x\right)}\right)\,dx\\&+&\int_{0}^{\pi/4}\left(\frac{1}{1+\tan^3\left(\frac{7\pi}{4}+x\right)}+\frac{1}{1+\tan^3\left(\frac{7\pi}{4}-x\right)}\right)\,dx \end{eqnarray*}$$
greatly simplifies into:
$$ \text{PV}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{dx}{1+\tan^3(x)} = \int_{0}^{3\pi/4}1\,dx+\int_{0}^{\pi/4}1\,dx = \color{red}{\pi}.$$